# Assign DHCP Scope by NIC Manufacturer MAC address?

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

I have a number of devices from the same manufacturer that I'd like to pre-assign addresses from a pool. EG XX:YY:ZZ:AA:BB:CC is a cluster of MAC all with the same first 3 groups (XX:YY:ZZ) but will have differing last set. I'd like to give them an address from a small pool of available addresses. I can't put them into a known host list due to the devices coming and going. Thoughts?

Comment: It sounds as though you want a normal dhcp server with a reserved mac address pool. It doesn't matter if the devices come and go for the IP address based on MAC list in the configuration file.

Comment: I can do a pool by full MAC, but I am trying to do a pool reservation by only the first half of the MAC.